# Flutter request at backend is printing encoded symbols

Tags: java, flutter, sockets, encoding, bufferedreader

I'm making a local request from Flutter using Android emulator using http library of Dart. When I clicked on a button following code execute in flutter which is used to make a call to local service which is running locally on port 8000.

```
void getRequest () async {
    Map<String, String> body = {
      "schoolName":"abcd"
    };
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "content-type": "application/json"
    };
    http.Response response =await http.post("https://10.0.2.2:8000/", headers: headers, body: jsonEncode(body));
  }
```

This is my URL for localhost : **https://10.0.2.2:8000/** as android emulator points to this only URL locally.

Code where I'm reading this request is as following:

```
int port;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    boolean running = true;
public void startServer () {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            this.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            try {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                if (socket.isConnected()) {
                    System.out.println("Server Starter");
                }

                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()).length() != 0) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        ServerClass serverClass = new ServerClass(8000);
        serverClass.startServer();
    }
```

And when I'm printing the request it looks like this i.e all of them are some encoded symbol:

```
 �  �`S>oV��!���;�nGu�k�f����l,!`3q  �+�/�,�0̨̩�    ��
� � � / 5 
  H   
  10.0.2.2   �   
        #
```

Also when I hit the same request with postman to the URL http://localhost:8000/, backend service is printing the correct request without any unknown symbols as above. Where am I going wrong in this flow?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this method its decodes utf8 first then decode the body

```
json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my question is when I'm printing the request at the backend it is printing the request in unknown symbols. How to get rid of these unknown symbols and prints the correct request? Currently I'm not worried about the response. Main point here is that why the request at the backend is some unknown symbols but when the same request hit from postman backend prints the correct request without any unknown symbols.